# User welcome message in php

Tags: php, mysql

How do I create a user welcome message in php. So that the user who has been logged on will be     able to see his username.
I have this code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","nitoryolai123$%^");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("school", $con);





$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users
WHERE Username='$username'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Username'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
?>
```

I'm trying to make use of the data that is inputted in this login form:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="verifylogin.php">
<td>
<table  border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="">
<tr>

<td  colspan="16" height="25"  style="background:#5C915C; color:white; border:white 1px solid; text-align: left"><strong><font size="2">Login User</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td width="30" height="35"><font size="2">Username:</td>
<td width="30"><input  name="myusername" type="text" id="idnum" maxlength="5"></td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td width="30" height="35" ><font size="2">Password:</td>
<td width="30"><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="lname" maxlength="15"></td>


</tr>

<td align="right" width="30"><td align="right" width="30"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></td> <td align="right" width="30"><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></td></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

But this, verifylogin.php, seems to be in the way.

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root"; 
$password="nitoryolai123$%^"; 
$db_name="school"; 
$tbl_name="users"; 


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];


$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


if($count==1){

session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:userpage.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

How do I do it? I always get this error when I run it:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\wamp\www\exp\userpage.php on line 53
```

Can you recommend of an easier on how I can achieve the same thing?

Comment: I don't get why you're querying the database for the username field when you're passing the username value in the WHERE clause. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also need to add an exit(); after the following code:

```
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:userpage.php");
exit(); ## EXIT REQUIRED
```

If you don't add this and the client refreshes they will be prompted with somethingh like 'Are you sure you wish to resubmit the posted variables?' And if they click yes then all you login logic will be executed again. In this case this may not be fatal thing, but you should till have it in anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$username'");
```

you forgot to define and fill $username from somewhere

Answer (score 0):

and most importantly: if a new user logs in, it needs to show a different name and not show the previous one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).